# primefaces p:selectOneMenu truncating long options (when selected)

Tags: jsf, select, primefaces, drop-down-menu

Has anyone had the issue of p:selectOneMenu truncating long options when those long options are selected? See jpg at https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU5Tn.jpg

This particular input has an inline style width of 130px which looks to be computed at run time (based on the particular options). I'm having the same issue with other selects that have different options - the longest option gets truncated in the display when it's selected.

XHTML is pretty plain jane, I've changed the values for posting here, but this is it:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectPaymentAcct2" value="#{myBean.myProp}"> 
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.myOptions}"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Do you define any widths yourself as well? In order to help you should post your xhtml code. I am using Primefaces 3.2 and did not have this issue yet.

Comment: Look for `width` option in PrimeFaces look and feel CSS you are using. FireBug will help.

Comment: The width is declared *inline*, there is no class.  Even if there were a class, the inline style would trump it.  <input type="text" value="Select one" tabindex="-1" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all" name="selectPaymentAcct_editableInput" style="cursor: pointer; width: 130px;">

Comment: Adding &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; to the end of options seems to "fix" the truncation (the spaces end up truncated, not the text), but I'd rather not have to do this.